# Project Management Typescript

Tags: typescript

How hard can it be to just share company-wide interfaces or classes that can be re-used in Typescript projects?

I haven't found any simple solution until now.

Regards, Peter

Comment: Wdym? You can simply have on interface file that you include in any project, that shouldn't be so hard

Answer (score 0):

So we use AWS-CodeArtifact for that. There you can create a internal domain, and publish npm packages to that domain.

In our CI/CD pipeline, there's a step, where the interfaces / classes are getting published.

Then every project can just run npm install 'generic interface' and work with that.